# Failed to fetch when testing apollo client in angular

Tags: angularjs, typescript, karma-jasmine, graphql, apollo

I am trying to build a simple app in Angular using Apollo. I have created a graphql server using the tool 'create-graphql-server' and I have it running on localhost:3000

I have a simple form and am able to create a user in the UI when I serve it. The problem is when I try to test it I get a 'failed to fetch' error. I am using Jasmine/Karma.

Here is the test file:

```
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone')
require('zone.js/dist/async-test')
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test')
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test')
require('zone.js/dist/proxy')
// var TestBed, getTestBed, async, inject = require('@angular/core/testing')
// var ApolloModule = require('apollo-angular')
// var ApolloClient, createNetworkInterface = require('apollo-client')
// var DataService = require('../data.service')
// var Profile = require('../../models/profile/profile.interface')
import { TestBed, getTestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ApolloModule } from 'apollo-angular';
import { ApolloClient, createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client';
import { DataService } from '../data.service'
import { Profile } from '../../models/profile/profile.interface'

// by default, this client will send queries to `/graphql` (relative to the URL of your app)
export function provideClient(): ApolloClient {
  return new ApolloClient({
    // see - http://dev.apollodata.com/angular2/cache-updates.html#dataIdFromObject
    dataIdFromObject: (o: any) => `${o.__typename}-${o.id},`,

    // see - http://dev.apollodata.com/angular2/initialization.html
    networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
      uri: 'https://localhost:3000/graphql',

    }),
  });;
}

let profile: Profile = {
    email: "test@testing.com",
    password: "tester7"
}

describe('User', () => {


    /***************************************************************
     * Configure Module to be used for Testing. 
     * Make Sure to add Services needed for testing
     ***************************************************************/
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ 
                ApolloModule.forRoot(provideClient)
            ],
            declarations: [
            ],
            providers: [
                DataService // We need the DataService to test
            ]
        }).compileComponents();

    })

    /***************************************************************
     * Can User account be created?
     ***************************************************************/
    it('Can be created', (done) => {
        let _ds: DataService = getTestBed().get(DataService);
        _ds.createUser(profile).subscribe((data) => {
            console.log("USER CAN BE CREATED: ", data);
            //expect(data).toContain("email");
            done();
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }, 2000);
})
```

DataService:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Apollo, ApolloQueryObservable } from 'apollo-angular';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import UserQueries from './helpers/user.queries'

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    token: String;
    userQueries = new UserQueries;

    qCreateUser = UserQueries.createUser;
    qUpdateUser = UserQueries.updateUser;
    qRemoveUser = UserQueries.removeUser;

    constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}

    theTruth() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Sign in using email and password given
     * Return Promise
     * 
     * @param email       Login email
     * @param password    Login password
     * @return Promise    Jsonified Result from fetch
     */
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String) {
        return fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify( { email, password } ),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).then((result) => {
            return result.json();
        })
    }

    /**
     * Create new user
     * 
     * @param params       Profile info to start account with
     * @return Observable  GQL Mutation observable
     */
    createUser(params) {
        let observable = this.apollo.mutate({
            mutation: this.qCreateUser,
            variables: params

            // // this will provide an update of the main AllUsers
            // // query so the list gets updated...
            // updateQueries: {
            //     AllUsers: (prev, { mutationResult }) => {
            //         const newUser = mutationResult.data.addUser;
            //         const prevAllUsers = prev.allUsers;

            //         return {
            //             allUsers: [...prevAllUsers, newUser]
            //         };
            //     },
            // },
        })
        return observable;
    }
}
```

And the error output:

Error: Network error: Failed to fetch
    at new ApolloError (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/sudo/projects/graphQL-NG/~/apollo-client/errors/ApolloError.js:34)
    at :9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/sudo/projects/graphQL-NG/~/apollo-client/core/QueryManager.js:183
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/sudo/projects/graphQL-NG/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/sudo/projects/graphQL-NG/~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/sudo/projects/graphQL-NG/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/sudo/projects/graphQL-NG/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:141)
    at :9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/sudo/projects/graphQL-NG/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:831
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/sudo/projects/graphQL-NG/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/sudo/projects/graphQL-NG/~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:103)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/sudo/projects/graphQL-NG/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423)

I'm a newbie so any direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came back to it and figured out that I was using https instead of http. D'oh!

It should be:

```
// by default, this client will send queries to `/graphql` (relative to the URL of your app)
export function provideClient(): ApolloClient {
  return new ApolloClient({
    // see - http://dev.apollodata.com/angular2/cache-updates.html#dataIdFromObject
    dataIdFromObject: (o: any) => `${o.__typename}-${o.id},`,

    // see - http://dev.apollodata.com/angular2/initialization.html
    networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
      uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',

    }),
  });;
}
```